# Fingerprint reader stuck on first scan

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I have a Zorin 15 OS, I'm trying to add a fingerprint unlock with the built-in feature. But it gets stuck on the first fingerprint scan and does not let me scan more times.
How could I resolve this issue.
I have also tried installing the fprint one but that one also gets stuck.

Edit; somehow this issue was fixed for me by installing Zoris 16.

Comment: Zorin OS isn’t supported here, but you may find an answer [at the Zorin Forum](https://forum.zorin.com/). Be sure to provide the brand and model of your notebook, as well as the output of `lsusb` so that someone there might have an answer 

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: @matigo Thanks will do